# Stewart's Theorem

Tags: geometry

In triangle $ABC$, angle $\angle A = 90^\circ$. Let $M$ be a point on the hypotenuse $BC$. Prove that $MB^2\left(AC^2\right)+MC^2\left(AB^2\right)=MA^2\left(BC^2\right)$.

Can someone please provide guidance as to how to go about this proof?

Comment: Have you *tried* to actually write down Stewart's theorem for that figure, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: i have written down stewart's theorem...so far I have (MA^2)(BC)=(AB^2)(MC)+(AC^2)(MB)-MBMCBC

Comment: Hint: multiply that by $BC$ and remember that $BC^2=AB^2+AC^2\,$.

Comment: okay so now i have (MA^2)(BC^2)=AB^2(BC)(MC)+AC^2(MC)(BC)-(MB)(MC)(AB^2+AC^2). i dont see how to get to MC^2 and MB^2...

Comment: Regroup and collect the terms on the RHS, for example: $AB^2\cdot BC\cdot MC - AB^2 \cdot MB \cdot MC = AB^2\cdot MC \cdot (BC - MB)=\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Note that $AQ = AC\cdot \frac{BM}{BC}$ and $AP = AB\cdot \frac{CM}{BC}$

Then $AM^2 = AP^2 + AQ^2 = \left(AC\cdot \frac{BM}{BC}\right)^2 + \left(AB\cdot \frac{CM}{BC}\right)^2$

So $AM^2\cdot BC^2 = BM^2\cdot AC^2 + CM^2\cdot AB^2$ as required.

Comment: this makes sense to me...however my professor wants us to use stewart's theorem instead of similar triangles.